# How to call NSString from json to UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uialertview

I would like to pass some values from json to a message of UIAlertView. I have some codes

```
- (void)jsonParse{

    NSString* path  = @"http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php";
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    NSDictionary* resultDic = [dic objectForKey:@"maxid"];
    NSString* recData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"recommendData"];
    NSString* rData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"];
    NSString* lData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"level"];

}

- (void)locationView
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Recommendation"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@."]
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                          otherButtonTitles: @"GO", nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

As I know, I have to do something in
`message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@."]`. However, I have no idea how to do it. Can someone tell me how to pass the values of lData and rData to the message of uialertview??

Comment: You should learn Objective-C first before start coding. This will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a global `NSString` variable which defines you message

In `.h` file

```
NSString *message;
```

In `jsonParse` method

```
- (void)jsonParse {
    //Your Stuff
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@", lData, rData];
}
```

and then in your `UIAlertView`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]     initWithTitle:@"Recommendation"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"GO", nil];

[alert show];
```

Comment: How do you use local variable of other function?

Comment: Edited the answer, you can check

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)jsonParse{

    //your code
    [self locationViewWithRoom:rData level:lData];

}

- (void)locationViewWithRoom:(NSString *)room level:(NSString *)level
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Recommendation"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@.", room, level]
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                          otherButtonTitles: @"GO", nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: but how to call this method?? - (void)locationViewWithRoom:(NSString *)room level:(NSString *)level. I need to call this alertview when press the button

Comment: if your button call -(void)jsonParse method will be called by my string after //your code mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Recommendation"
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@.", iData, rData]
                                               delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                      otherButtonTitles: @"GO", nil];
```

Just write the values after you write the argument for **stringWithFormat**. The number of your arguments should match with the number of `%@s` used in argument string, and your arguments should be comma separated, otherwise you will get a build error.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty easy. You are doing right just few things are missing.

1. Declare `rData` & `lData` as properties in your class,

   ```
   @interface <classname>
   @propert (nonatomic,strong) NSString *lData;
   @propert (nonatomic,strong) NSString *rData;
   @end
   ```
2. Then your string can be formed using,

   ```
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@.", lData, rData];
   ```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I have tried this before but it still shows unused variable lData and rData in NSString* rData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"]. That's why I have bit of confusing

Comment: add this >@implementation <className> >@synthesis lData,rData; >@end And use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@.", lData,rData];

Answer (score 0):

Declare both the variables (rData & lData) globally (means, in your interface) and then use it like this

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Recommendation"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK! There is another collection which located at room %@ in level %@.",lData,rData]
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                          otherButtonTitles: @"GO", nil];
```